# Share Whatsapp link breaks after hash

Tags: html, share, href, whatsapp

So I'm trying to share a link which includes a hashtag with Whatsapp.

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=www.google.com#test" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

Somehow it will send www.google.com but it ignores everything after the #.
Anyone has a solution for this? You would rock my world!

PS. I tried to encode the #test but that doesn't work either.

Comment: it's because `#` to the `a` tag means target id. it's going to www.google.com and then it searches for a DOM element called test. Try Arjen's answer, might be better using entity codes rather than straight up chars

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I change the link you posted to this:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%23test" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">Share via Whatsapp</a>
```

In whatsapp is shows as http://google.com#test

Comment: So it turns out this works! I think something went wrong when I tested the encoded version the first time. Thanks!